# Power BI limits OData.Query to WorkItemSnapshot in Azure DevOps Server by 10000 rows

Tags: azure, odata, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-devops-server

I'm making report about work progress in my company, how remaining/completed work is changed during time associated with given Epic work item.

I'm using:

- Azure DevOps Server 2019
- Power BI Desktop 64 bit `Version: 2.65.5313.5141 64-bit (January 2019)`
- OData query to select data from Azure DevOps Server

So I've found an issue.

- When I'm getting information about workitems through this element `WorkItems`:

```
let
    Tasks = OData.Feed("http://{localserver}:8080/tfs/{collName}/{projName}/_odata/v1.0/WorkItems?$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Task')")
in
    Tasks
```

I get all elements (65348 rows)

- When I'm getting information about workitems through this element `WorkItemSnapshot`:

```
let
    Tasks = OData.Feed("http://{localserver}:8080/tfs/{collName}/{projName}/_odata/v1.0/WorkItems?$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Task')")
in
    Tasks
```

I get only 10000 rows.

So, due to documentation, when using Power BI Desktop, PBI itself should load all paginated data. But as I see, it does not do it addressing `WorkItemSnapshot` model element.

How could I  bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found reason of such behaviour:

```
VS403510: The Snapshot tables in Analytics are intended to be used only in an aggregation.  The result for this query has been reduced to preview of a single result page. Details on recommended query patterns are available here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=861060
```

So it is rather restriction of Azure DevOps Server